# Payment for uploading app into android market

Tags: android

Registration fee is 25$. It will only be for one year? After one year we have to pay 25$ or it will expire? How much do we have to pay for renewal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"There is a **one time** $25 registration fee"

Extracted from [here](http://support.google.com/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=113468)